# JQuery Ajax Not Showing Success Alert

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to get JQuery Ajax to work but not getting a success alert.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(
        $('button').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'testing123.php',
                success: function(){
                    alert('this worked');
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    ));
</script>

<button>Click Here</button>
```

...then the testing123.php file:

```
<?php
    echo 'Hello there';
?>
```

I DO have JQuery library added too.

When I click the button I should be getting an alert saying "this worked" right?

I don't understand why it's not happening...

Any ideas why?

Comment: Check the developer tools console for any javascript errors?

Comment: is *testing123.php* in the same directory as this file?

Comment: parentheses were not properly use closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incorrect use of parantheses. Corrected code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {    
            $('button').click(function() {    
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'testing123.php',
                    success: function(){
                      alert('this worked');
                    }
                });    
                return false;    
            });    
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to put hash along with button id ('#button').click

`$(document).ready(function() {

            $('#button').click(function() {

                $.ajax({

                    url: 'testing123.php',

                    success: function(){

                      alert('test echo');

                    }

                });

                return false;

            });

  });`

Comment: you need to provide id in button and use that id in jquery <button id='button'>click here</button>

Comment: -1 no need of `id` in this case. he did't properly closed the parenthesis.