# jquery on ajax succes make fade out div

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I have to make a fade out message div on ajax success function.The fade out message will show on the top of the page for sometimes if ajax return successfully data. can anyone help.

Comment: can you post your jQuery and HTML markup code?

Comment: Please post what u have tried

Comment: This one will help you --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356844/jquery-ajax-not-showing-success-alert

Comment: Very poorly asked question, please improve it

Comment: whenever asked question, please put your code with problem, so no discussion need for understanding exact problem

Comment: @all the easy way is just to ignore this kind of really poor question, and vote to close

Answer (score 1):

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: "script.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        id: menuId
    },
    success: function () {
        $("#msgbox").fadeOut()
    }
});
```

That would be something like this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(data) {
$(".message_div").show().delay(2000).fadeOut(600);
}
```